# How to make progressDrawable occupy entire width of seeker (Android)?

Tags: android, width, customization, android-seekbar

I am trying to create a custom seekbar. I have used vectors for progress drawable and thumb as:

```
 android:thumb="@drawable/custom_seekbar_thumb"
 android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar_progress"
 android:splitTrack="false"
```

Right now my seekbar looks like this:

[image: My seekbar]

As you can see the pink vector image that I have used for progressDrawable doesn't occupy the entire width of seekbar -  there is some gap between the drawable and  seekbar in the right side.

How do I make my progress drawable occupy the entire width of the seekbar?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this issue simply by using `android:paddingEnd="0dp"` in Seekbar.